# Latency doubles with two (from one) audio / video sources in the audiomixer or the compositor

Tags: gstreamer

Sorry if this question is vague, I'm trying to troubleshoot latency in an application that uses both an `audiomixer` as well as a video `compositor`.

I noticed that with one audio/video endpoint, RTT latency is about 150 ms. When another audio/video endpoint joins in, RTT latency jumps to 400 ms.

Is there any simple checks or simple configurations that might cause this behaviour?